# Centering logo-image and put the responsive navbar right under the logo

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<nav id="navbar-custom" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="GIỚI THIỆU.HTML"><img src="logo.png" alt="logo-Image"></a>
    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav mynavbar">
        <li><a id="menu_link" href="GIỚI THIỆU.html">GIỚI THIỆU</a></li>
        <li><a id="menu_link" href="#EVAALUTION">ĐÁNH GIÁ</a></li>
        <li><a id="menu_link" href="ĐĂNG KÝ.HTML">ĐĂNG KÝ</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
```

I am stuck on making a responsive pronunciation-teaching website with logo right on in the top-middle of the page and put the menu right beneath the logo. How I can do that with bootstrap?
[all i want is make my web as the photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZsQe.png)

Comment: add a jsFiddle please

Comment: If you are satisfied with my answer .Please give me a tick ...at bottom of my answer's voting section

Answer (score 1):

It's best that your learn CSS in general before hopping into Twitter Bootstrap.

Also, please post a jsfiddle or jsbin of your code.

You could center it simply with:

```
.logo {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Otherwise you can use the Bootstrap grid system to pseudo-center the logo.

Comment: Make sure there is a set width on the logo.

Comment: i adjusted the height down to 150px. i dont know how to set the width in order to keep the original shape for the photo? can you tell me how?

Answer (score 0):

Just a class **logo** and add following css to that class

```
  .logo{margin: 0 auto;}
```

To learn CSS log on to [site](http://www.codecademy.com)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your logo within col-xs-12 so it will take the full width of your navbar container - you can pull it left/right/center it within later on:

```
<div class='col-xs-12'><a class="navbar-brand" href="GIỚI THIỆU.HTML"><img src="logo.png" alt="logo-Image"></a></div>
```

I'm not really sure if this is what you want to achieve but there you go.

Answer (score 0):

i have used class extra small with logo

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Bootstrap Example</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>

<nav id="navbar-custom" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container">
<div class="navbar-header">
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
<span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12">   <a class="navbar-brand " href="GIỚI THIỆU.HTML"><img src="logo.png" alt="logo-Image"></a></div>
<div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav mynavbar">
<li><a id="menu_link" href="GIỚI THIỆU.html">GIỚI THIỆU</a></li>
<li><a id="menu_link" href="#EVAALUTION">ĐÁNH GIÁ</a></li>
<li><a id="menu_link" href="ĐĂNG KÝ.HTML">ĐĂNG KÝ</a></li>
</ul>
</div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: sorry but how can i css  to make it like the photo at the bottom of my post bro?